# Vicidial Group queue to call the next number if the first one is unavailable, busy or rejects the call

Tags: asterisk, sip

we have created a Group in Vicidial and added few remote agents to the group. Remote agents have mobile phone numbers. Here are some of the options from the group configurations:

```
Next Agent Call: longest_wait_time
Queue Priority: 0 - Even
On-Hook Ring Time: 15
```

Now the queue is working as expected. Agent numbers are dialed based on the wait time. But the problem is that for an incoming call, the system dialed only one number from the queue and hangs up if the call is not answered.
It does not dialed the next number from the queue if the previous number does not receive the call. It only dialed the next number if a new call comes in.

I was wondering how to have the next number from the queue dialed (or redirect the user to an IVR) if the previous number does not picks up?

**Vicidial:**

```
Version: 2.14b0.5
SVN Version: 3254
DB Schema Version: 1596
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a way, in my case all the agents are remote agent on PSTN connections. So I have set the `On-Hook = Y` for all the remote agent accounts. And now if the previous agent is busy or does not receive the call then the next agent is dialed from the queue.

Need to check if setting the On-Hook property to Y has any other ramification.

**Update:** You have to set the onhook time considering 5/6 seconds will be spent on the PSTN end to search for the mobile device + couple of seconds to initiate the call + ring time on the mobile device. In my case setting 23 seconds working ok for a 15 seconds ring time on the mobile end.